# Representing vertices as spheres in Graphics 3D

Tags: graphics3d, vector, chemistry

I'm representing a portion of molecule, P3HT, in Mathematica as a pentagon that I build using Polygon and Graphics3D.

I would like to represent the vertices of the pentagon as spheres(corresponding to atoms).

If possible I would like to add a vector perpendicular to the P3HT plane stemming from the centroid of the plane.

Here's what I have so far:

The atomic coordinates:

```
C1 := {-1.51767 , 2.46541, -0.0036}
C2 := {-1.15943, 1.11229, -0.00326}
C3 := {0.25701, 0.88881, -0.00082}
C4 := {0.9979, 2.09239, 0.00071}
S := {-0.10561, 3.33212, -0.00095}
```

The molecular plane, defined by the atomic coordinates:

```
P3HTPlane = Polygon[{{-1.51767`, 2.46541`, -0.0036`}, {-1.15943`, 
1.11229`, -0.00326`}, {0.25701`, 0.88881`, -0.00082`}, {0.9979`, 
2.09239`, 0.00071`}, {-0.10561`, 3.33212`, -0.00095`}}]
```

The centroid of the plane:

```
OO = RegionCentroid[P3HTPlane]
```

The plot of the plane with the centroid included:

```
Graphics3D[{LightOrange, P3HTPlane, Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[OO]}, 
BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

In case it helps, here's the molecule I'm working with:

```
ChemicalData["3-hexylthiophene", "MoleculePlot"]
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can draw a sphere centered at `C1` with radius say 0.1 using `Sphere[C1, 0.1]`. You can draw multiple spheres using `Sphere[C1, 0.1], Sphere[C2, 0.1], ...` or just `Sphere[{C1, C2, ...}, 0.1]` for short. You'll want to remove the `BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}` option though or the spheres won't look like spheres.

Comment: Awesome! I got the whole thing working. Thank you very much!